# Django. Celery delay() not printing to terminal

Tags: django, celery

I have a simple Celery task in Django:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task
def celery_test(x, y):
    print x + y
    return None
```

I call it in a view:

```
...
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        celery_test.delay("uno ", "dos")
        ...
```

So, when I call the function with `delay` it doesn't print anything to the terminal, why?, ... when I call it whithout `delay` it prints things correctly. I'm using RabbitMQ server and it is running fine.

Comment: Is the task even picked up by worker?

Comment: how are you running the celery worker? where is its log output going?

Answer (score 2):

Check your log file for celery. It'll probably print it there.

### EDIT

When you use `.delay()` the task is decoupled from the terminal and all you get printed is something like this:

```
AsyncResult: 3df665f1-547d-49bb-937b-8190a63bfeb7.
```

What happens is that you've passed the code to the broker and the broker can't print back to terminal. But if you have a print statements in your code they'll be printed into your celery log.

Comment: Nor sure why this is downvoted. But when you use .delay() the task is decoupled from the terminal and all you get is something like this:

<AsyncResult: 3df665f1-547d-49bb-937b-8190a63bfeb7>

You've passed the code to the broker and the broker can't print back to terminal. But if you have print statements in your code they'll be printed into your celery log. Bah.